# What is the regex that allows alphanumeric and '-' special character that also should be in between the text not at the begining or ending

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, regex, mern

All the special character except hyphen are not allowed.
Other conditions:

```
-xnnw729 //not allowed
nsj28w- // not allowed
aks82-z2s0j // allowed
```

Comment: If it is duplicate then please share the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one I was looking for is

```
^([\w+\d+_]+)((-)([\w+\d+_]+))*
```

Answer (score 1):

Some notes about your answer:

- Using `\w` also matches `\d` and `_`
- For a match only you don't need all the capture groups
- If you want to validate the whole line, you can append `$` to assert the end of the line
- Using a plus sign in the character class `[\w+\d+_]` matches a `+` character and is the same as `[\w+]`

You can simplify your pattern to:

```
^\w+(?:-\w+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/thWdQ8/1)